# React updating props with state data

Tags: reactjs, state, forum

I have a Component that is handling a contact forum submission from a user.  I want to take the state that the user submits and add it to my props data.  Right now everything is working, but the handleSubmit, I am not sure how to take the state and pass it to my this.data.props to update the data to include the new object.

My data is an array of Objects.  The state takes user input and updates itself.  Next I want to take the state object and add it to my props.data and then display it on the screen.

EDIT:  UPDATED WITH LATEST CODE

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';


const testData = [
    {
        name: 'Joe',
        email: 'joemail'
    },

    {
        name: 'Bill',
        email: 'billmail'
    },

    {
        name: 'Dude',
        email: 'dudemail'
    }
]

class FormContact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            formValues: {
                name: '',
                email: ''
            }
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        let formValues = this.state.formValues;
        let name = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;

        formValues[name] = value;
        this.setState({
            formValues
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("NEW FORM VALUES " + this.state.formValues.name + " " + this.state.formValues.email);
        const {name, email} = this.state.formValues
        this.props.addContact({name, email});
    }

    render() {      
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
               <label> Name:
                   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value={this.state.formValues["name"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
               </label><br />
               <label> Email:
                   <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.formValues["email"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
               </label><br />
                   <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        )
    }
}

FormContact.PropTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.object
    )
}

FormContact.defaultProps = {
    data: testData
}

class Contact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: testData
        }
    }

     addContact(contact) {
         this.setState({data: this.state.data.concat(contact)});
     }


    render() {
        const renObjData = this.props.data.map( (anObjectMapped, index) => {
            return (<p key={index}>
                        Name: {anObjectMapped.name} < br/>
                        Email: {anObjectMapped.email} <br /></p>
            )
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>CONTACT PAGE</h1>
            <FormContact data={this.state.data} addContact={this.addContact.bind(this)} />
                {renObjData}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


Contact.PropTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.object
    )
}

Contact.defaultProps = {
    data: testData
}


export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at here is having a parent container that passes down `data` as props to the form component. You already have your `Contact` component so you can make it hold the data state.

How it would work is you would write a function on the Contact component called `addContact` and it would take a contact as an argument and then set its own state with the new contact IE concat it to its own data array through setting state.

```
class Contact extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        data: testData
      }
    }


   addContact = (contact) => {
     this.setState({data: this.state.data.concat(contact)});
   };



  render() {
    const contacts = _.map(this.state.data, (value, index) => {
      return <li key={index + value}> {value.email}  {value.name} </li>
    })
    return (
     <div>
       <h1>CONTACT PAGE</h1>
       <FormContact data={this.state.data} addContact={this.addContact} />
       <h3> Contacts</h3>
       <ul>{contacts} </ul>
     </div>
   )
  }
}
```

and then in your handleSubmit function all you have to do is add

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const {name, email} = this.state.formValues
  this.props.addContact({name, email})
}
```

this will push it onto the data array in the parent component and then once the parent component updates it will pass that down as props to the form component.

Here is a code pen showing all that in action. http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/VKPXoN

UPDATE: Also in Contacts added how to display data, you can easily replace lodash `_.map` with `this.state.data.map(function(value, index)`

Comment: data seems to be undefined in this   this.setState({data: this.state.data.concat(contact)});

Comment: had to add this.addContact.bind(this) and now it points to the data correctly.  Its now adding data to my array of objects but not updating the print value on screen  -  only has the first 3 contacts displayed and not any new ones I add

Comment: can you update your post with newest code so can take a peek

Comment: `const renObjData = this.props.data.map( (anObjectMapped, index) => {`

That needs to be `this.state.data.map` not props